# how can i change only the first letter of a filename into uppercase?

Tags: python, filenames

```
import os

def soldier(ppth):
            pth= os.listdir(ppth)
            for filename in pth:
                os.rename(filename,filename.lower())
            print(pth)
soldier("D://QwertyA")
```

Comment: Even if i use os.rename(filename,filename.capitalize()). Its generating an error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'asd.docx' -> 'Asd.docx'

Comment: You probably need to use the full path to the file `f"{ppth}/{filename}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the capitalize method.

`string.capitalize()`

```
def soldier(ppth):             
    pth= os.listdir(ppth)             
    for filename in pth:                 
        os.rename(f"{ppth}/{filename}",f"{ppth}/{filename.lower().capitalize()}")
```

Comment: No!! i want to capitalize the first letters of the file present in the specific directory

Comment: Right.

```import os

def soldier(ppth):
            pth= os.listdir(ppth)
            for filename in pth:
                os.rename(filename,filename.lower().capitalize())
            print(pth)
soldier("D://QwertyA")
```

Comment: This is exact what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
import os
fileName = 'test.txt'
newFileName = fileName.capitalize()
print(newFileName)
os.rename(f'/path/to/file/{fileName}',f'/path/to/file{newFileName}')
```

Seems like my file has been capitalized.

[image]